# How to execute jQuery code depending upon the value received through querystring?

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

Let me explain the question in detail. I'm using PHP and smarty. 
I'm getting a value `op=back` from query-string. But this is not going to happen everytime the PHP file runs, so when `op=back` is the value I've to fir a click event on a specific link. My PHP file code snippet is given below :

```
<?php  
  include_once("includes/teacher-application-header.php");

  prepare_request();
  $request = empty( $_GET ) ? $_POST : $_GET ;
  $op = $request['op'];

  $objTeachClassSub = new TeacherClassesSubjects();

  global $teacher_profile_from_session;

  $teacher_id = $teacher_profile_from_session['TEACHER_ID'];

  $teacher_classes_subjects = $objTeachClassSub->GetClassSubjectMappingsbyTeacherId($teacher_id);

$smarty->assign('teacher_classes_subjects', $teacher_classes_subjects); 

  $smarty->assign("op",$op);        
  $smarty->display("teacher-details.tpl");      
?>
```

Now the code snippet from smarty file is as below:

```
{literal}
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
{/literal}
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
          <h3>Teacher Details</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="99%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="manage_box" >
    <tr>
      <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="25%">
            {if $teacher_classes_subjects}
               {foreach from=$teacher_classes_subjects item="classes_subjects"}
                 <b><a href="#" id="{$classes_subjects.class_id}">{$classes_subjects.class_name}</a></b><br />
                 {if $classes_subjects.class_subjects}
                 <div id="class_subjects_{$classes_subjects.class_id}">
                   {foreach from=$classes_subjects.class_subjects item="class_subjects"}
                        <i><a id ="back" href="chapter_details.php?class_id={$classes_subjects.class_id}&cs_map_id={$class_subjects.cs_map_id}">{$class_subjects.subject_name}</a></i><br />
                   {/foreach}
                 </div>
                 <br />
                 {/if}
               {/foreach}
            {/if}
          </td>  
          <td width="75%">
          {if $chapter_details}
            <ul>
            {foreach from=$chapter_details item=chapter}
            <li><a href="chapter_details.php?op=get_chapter_theory&chapter_id={$chapter.chapter_id}&class_id={$class_id}&cs_map_id={$cs_map_id}&chapter_title={$chapter.chapter_title}">{$chapter.chapter_title}</a></li>
            {/foreach}
            </ul>
          {/if}

          {include file=$file_to_show}
          </td>  aly what is
        </tr>
      </table>
        </td>
    <td align="left" id="subject_container" valign="top">
    </td>
    <td align="left" id="chapter_container" valign="top">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now what I want to achieve is to write a jQuery code in the above smart template file which will execute if the op value is back(i.e.`{op==back}`). 
Actually what is expected is when the `op=back` click event should get fire on the following link:

```
<a id ="back" href="chapter_details.php?class_id={$classes_subjects.class_id}&cs_map_id={$class_subjects.cs_map_id}">{$class_subjects.subject_name}</a>
```

Can anyone explain me how to achieve this functionality? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to an specific site when op==back you should just redirect it in you php code

```
 if(isset($_GET['op']) && $_GET['op'] == 'back'){
      header('location: yourpath/youurl.php');
 }
```

Remember to do this before echoing anything.

If you want to trigger a click when this option is set just print an script conditionally with a document ready and a $('#back').trigger('click') if you are using jQuery:

```
 //$go = (isset($_GET['op']) && $_GET['op'] == 'back');
 {if $go}
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#back').trigger('click');
   });
 </script>
 {/if}
```

EDIT

Clicking on that link will make the browser got to another page, unless you have used something like e.preventDefault(). If you haven't I would recommend using the first solution i proposed.
If you need the request to get to the client, an then redirect, for any reason, or you do something else I would use the second solution.

Hope it helps

Comment: I want to fire click event on a link only, I don't want to redirect to any URL. When I click on a link few values are passing in the form of query string upon clicking on the link. So your solution seems a bit unfit for this problem. Do you have any better idea other than this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your best option is to set it to a hidden html input in your template, and in your java script in the document ready checking the value of that html input, then changing the href attribute of your link

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work if you put in header

```
<?php
    if($_GET['op'] == "back"){
        ?>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#back').trigger('click');
       });
     </script>
        <?php
        }
?>
```

but if you need to do this after your page is loaded completly you can set timer in JQuery and execute this Jquery script after may be 1 second

Comment: Or Create a function and call that function on body load

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in pure JS to retrieve the query string value of parameters and then use it to decide if you should fire the link click.

something like this:

```
function getQueryStringParameter(name) {

    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var n = getQueryStringParameter('op');
if(n == 'back'){
    $('#back').trigger('click');
}
```

hope it helps.